# Merge 2 Rows to 1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following rows on my query:

[image]

I would like to merge these rows to one row that will be presented as below:

[image]

Please note that my table holds more rows like this, so dynamic solution would be appreciated. In addition, There is several rows that will have NULL value in either Number 1 or Number 2 columns.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses aggregation functions:

```
select category, category_2,
       max(number_1) as number_1, max(number_2) as number_2
from t
group by category, category_2;
```

You may also be able to fix the underlying query, so it does not return multiple rows.  If that is of interest, then ask *another* question, with the query in the question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I can't fix the underlying query since this is the information I got from the client query.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what's the key (let's assume `Category`), you can do grouping:

```
select Category, max(Category2) as Category2, max(number1) as number1, max(number2) as number2
from table
group by Category
```

If `Category` and `Category2` together form the key, you could write:

```
select Category, Category2, max(number1) as number1, max(number2) as number2
from table
group by Category, Category2
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS SHOULD WORK. THIS WILL ADDRESS THE ISSUE OF THE QUERY RETURNING MULTIPLE ROWS

```
DECLARE @MERGE TABLE (Category VARCHAR(10),    Category_2 VARCHAR(10),  
                      Number_1 INT,  Number_2 INT)
INSERT INTO @MERGE VALUES
('A', 'B', NULL,1),
('A', 'B', 5,NULL)

SELECT
 A.Category 
,A.Category_2   
,MAX(A.Number_1) AS Number_1        
,MAX(B.Number_2) AS Number_2

FROM  @MERGE A INNER JOIN @MERGE B
ON A.Category=B.Category
WHERE B.Number_2 IS NOT NULL
AND B.Number_2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  A.Category ,A.Category_2
```

OUTPUT

```
Category    Category_2  Number_1    Number_2
  A            B           5          1
```